# UIPicker does not appear in app

Tags: ios, uipicker

I was putting an UIPicker in the app but it does not appear in the app when I run it on my actual device.  This is my until now

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [genreNames count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [genreNames objectAtIndex:row];
}


self.genreNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"t", @"p", @"s",
                     @"c", @"h", @"h", nil];
```

And in the .h file I am doing the correct declaration.

Do I have some missing code?

**Update** 
Yes I used the simulator, and yes I cannot see the picker at all. I am using story board, to which I added the picker. Sorry for lack of info.

Comment: Do you see it when you run it in simulator? Are your using Storyboards, or nibs?

Comment: Do you see the picker with no rows or you don't see the picker at all. You need to be more specific about what you see and add details about how you create the picker.

Comment: How have u added the UIPicker? interface builder? with code?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer this question as it seems very basic, yet you haven't given us a lot to work on.

My best guess is that the UIPickerView that you have in you UIViewController in the Interface Builder is not actually hooked up to any code, and it is also probably not set up as a data source. And although you say that you have the correct declarations in the .h file, we haven't seen that and they might be (not saying that they are) wrong.

But that might only be the tip of the iceberg.

While I could explain how to do this, there might very well be other problems that you will have in your UIPickerView adventures (This is the second, correct?). I think that it might be best for you to follow the instructions laid out [in this tutorial](http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-7-using-the-uipickerview/). That way, if anything does not work, you could just reread the tutorial and find out what it is you did wrong, and fix it yourself.